# ASP.NET MVC3 has some built-in "remember me" log in thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and I need to build a "Remember Me" feature. I'm just interested if there is a built-in thing for this purpose? If there is than maybe someone can show me how to use it?

Comment: Have you tried creating MVC 3 Project, and run it?  The thing you want to see is already in the default sample application.

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619791/implementing-remember-me-feature-in-asp-net-mvc) for a possible answer...

Answer (score 1):

The forms authentication provider has a boolean parameter for this. It's not implemented by default as far as I know in ASP.NET MVC.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented by default. In visual studio 2010 with mvc 3 create a new web site with the internet template and the template will create a solution that includes an account controller with a logon action that has the remember me feature using the asp.net membership provider.