# Create a Remember me functionality in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can i create a cookie that store the user name and password when user clicks remember me? check box.

Answer (score 0):

For Remember me functionality yours Action will go like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model) {

 //Implementaion for authorization
.......

var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
  1,
  userId,  //user id
  DateTime.Now,
  DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),  // expiry
  rememberMe,  //boolean value true for remember
  "", //roles 
  "/"
);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,   FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: before you copy code from other places you should at least tell them where you got it from. In this case, just redirect to the source:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619791/implementing-remember-me-feature-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Thanks bt It takes rememberMe value always false and rememberMe is not a property of class.

Comment: You will have to add `rememberMe` to class. so while creating ticket the appropriate value will get set.