# MVC4 Forms Authentication Auto Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, session-state, session-timeout

So, what I am trying to accomplish is a basic "remember me" style action for users of my application.

I have completed writing everything so far, and it is working as expected most of the time. Occasionally though, the method to check for the persistent Forms Authentication ticket doesn't auto login, and I can't figure out why it is only happening *occasionally*.

To test my code, what I have done is start the debugger, manually kill my session cookie in chrome's dev tools, then reload the page. Stepping through the code, it enters into the auto login method as expected and proceeds to reset my session data. However, if I wait an inordinate amount of time, like 4 hours perhaps, and try the same thing it does not auto reset my session. (Assuming that i've left the debugger running for that amount of time).

**EDIT**: For clarity's sake, when this error is happening, I can open the dev tools and see that the authentication ticket is still available. It's just the code to reset my session is either not running, for erroring out somewhere. Due to the infrequency in which this is happening, it's hard to track down.

So, onto the code.

I'm calling the static void auto login method in the controller's constructor, and passing the httpcontext into the auto login method.

**Controller**

```
public class SiteController : Controller
{
    public SiteController()
    {
       this.UserAutoLogin(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    }

    // GET: /Site/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CatNav = this.RenderNavCategories();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Auto Login Code**

```
public static void UserAutoLogin(this Controller Controller, System.Web.HttpContext context)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);

    if (cookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        if (ticket != null)
        {
            if (ticket.Name.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (context.Session["UserName"] == null)
                    {
                        //get user from db
                        PersonRepository PersonRepo = new PersonRepository();
                        PersonModel Member = PersonRepo.GetUserUserName(ticket.Name);

                        if (Member.FirstName != null) //if this is null...then the cookie is wrong, so don't do shit
                        {
                            //Set the session parameters
                            context.Session["FirstName"] = Member.FirstName;
                            context.Session["LastName"] = Member.LastName;
                            context.Session["UserId"] = Member.Id;
                            context.Session["UserName"] = Member.Username;
                            context.Session["Email"] = Member.Email;
                            context.Session["IsUser"] = 1;
                            context.Session["Zip"] = Member.Zip;

                            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Member.Username, true);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // don't do anything for now - do something smart later :)                        
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619791/implementing-remember-me-feature-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Appreciate the reply, but that doesn't really help me any.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're passing HttpContext.Current to AutoLogin method, instead of using the one from Controller and then ignoring it when getting the cookie (calling HttpContext.Current again)? It looks like you have no idea what you're doing there.

Comment: Not really, I imported this bit of code from an old project and forgot to update that part. Good spot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when IIS is recycling the app, a new machine key is generated. The FormsAuthentication ticket is signed using that key so when the key changes the old ticket isn't recognized. You need to use a fixed machine key.

**Edit**: Removed link to key generator site (now defunct)

Comment: This seems to be working, I think you hit it on the head Mike. Thanks!

Comment: This link is taking to some Chinese website